# Is this graphing calculator broken, or is this someting really weird?

Tags: chaos-theory

The function is $y=x!-(\text{floor}(\sqrt{x!})^2-1)$, with $\text{floor}(x!)$ being the floor function of $x!$

[image: no]

Comment: No, the Gamma function just gets large quickly and there are oscillations probably because of the floor

Comment: The fact that the curve is below the horizontal axis in places also indicates that rounding errors are occuring (because the expression should always be at least 1). This is not surprising, since the numbers involved are enormous.

Comment: As Maximillian pointed out, whenever Desmos sees a factorial in a function, it immediately replaces it with $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$. The gamma function (see below) is defined over all of $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence there are some clear rounding issues and funky things going on when using it with the floor function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: Which part of the graph do you find strange?

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This generates the sequence
$$\{1,1,2,3,9,21,45,141,321,477,3585,12312,4605,74880,414120,2071776,5703552,\cdots
   \}$$

For the sequence
$$a_n=n!-\left\lfloor \sqrt{n!}\right\rfloor ^2$$ have a look at sequence $A066857$ in $OEIS$.

Comment: When I plugged in 4, 5, and 7 I got 0.